# Fallo en la conexion Mysql Wordpress vía PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**Buenas tengo el siguiente fallo de conexión con la base de datos:**

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:3306' (0) in /var/www/vhosts/test_OK.php on line 150
>
> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /var/www/vhosts/test_OK.php on line 151
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /var/www/vhosts/test_OK.php on line 153
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /var/www/vhosts/test_OK.php on line 153

**El codigo que hace mencion es:**

```
require 'wp-config.php';
$idcon = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
mysqli_select_db ($idcon, DB_NAME);
$sqlNR = "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = '$post_nombre' ";
$resNR = mysqli_query ($idcon, $sqlNR) or die ( mysqli_error($idcon) );
//Comprobamos si existe el registro en la base de datos, para introducirlo en DB o NO introducirlo.
    if( mysqli_num_rows ( $resNR ) >= 1 ){
        echo "Ya existe.";
    }else{
        echo "NO existe.";
    }
```

Recordar que es un Wordpress, y seguro que estoy haciendo algo mal en la consulta.
Bueno Gracias de Antemano.

Comment: Todo parece indicar que la constante `DB_HOST` está mal definida en tu `wp-config.php`. La tienes definida así: `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:3306');` y por lo tanto no conecta. Si eso no afecta a tu Wordpress, cambia la constante por  `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');` o bien en el código, en vez de usar la constante del archivo, escribe `localhost`, algo así: `$idcon = mysqli_connect('localhost', DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);` Cuando le pasas esto en el host: `localhost:3306`, la conexión no funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### El problema

Cuando usas `mysqli_connect` tú no puedes pasar en el parámetro correspondiente al host (`localhost`), el puerto (`3306`) de esta manera:

```
'localhost:3306'
```

En el Manual de PHP se indica claramente que, en caso de necesidad, esos parámetros se pasarían aparte. [(Ver en el Manual, la sintaxis y la lista de parámetros en el orden en que deben pasarse](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.construct.php)).

El mensaje de error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host
>   'localhost:3306' (0) in /var/www/vhosts/test_OK.php on line 150

Indica que en la constante de Wordpress `DB_HOST`, tú tienes definido el host y el puerto juntos. O sea, que en tu `wp-config.php` parece estar así:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:3306');
```

---

### Soluciones

No es necesario indicar el puerto cuando te conectas a MySQL. Lo puedes ver en los [ejemplos de conexión](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php) que ofrece el mismo Manual de PHP.

Dicho eso, entonces puedes resolver el problema de dos maneras.

#### 1. Modificar la constante en `wp-config.php`

Si no afecta tu Wordpress, puedes modificar la constante, así en `wp-config.php`:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Y luego sí debería conectar:

```
$idcon = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

#### 2. Escribir el host *a mano*

Si el cambio sugerido en (1) afectara a tu Wordpress, puedes escribir el host *a mano*:

```
$idcon = mysqli_connect('localhost', DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

---

**NOTA:**

Wordpress permite también conectar a la base de datos con su propia variable global. Aunque no me conste, tengo la intuición de que usar la variable global de WP para las conexiones a la base de datos podría ser más pesado y más costoso.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, al final lo he solucionado como mencionabas en la segunda opción. Ya que como mencionas puede ser que luego de fallos en registros si edito directamente desde DB_HOST, así que muchas gracias @A. Cedano

Comment: acerca de la nota, el impacto no suele ser muy notable al usar la clase wpdb y agrega toda la funcionalidad de dicha clase, todo dependerá de las tareas o acciones que se quieran realizar sobre la db. en este hilo (englisch) se muestra como incluir una versión mínima del wordpress y acceder al framework del cms https://stackoverflow.com/a/25158840/1423096